# Implantação do SQLite junto com aplicação .NET

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados, sqlite, deploy

Finalizei o app C# com o SQLite, porém vi que preciso mandar junto com a base e o DLL do SQLite. Quais os arquivos DLL do SQLite preciso anexar e qual pasta tenho que jogar esses arquivos?

A instalação do programa será feita em um computador local usando o XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende de como você está usando o SQLite. O mais óbvio é o `System.Data.SQLite.DLL` usado pelo ADO.NET. Se usar o LINQ com ele precisará do `System.Data.SQLite.Linq.DLL` também. Precisará também do `SQLite.Interop.DLL` (que é o SQLite).

É bom testar em uma máquina limpa para ver se instala tudo ok. Certifique-se que todas configurações estão ok.

Claro que se você já tem uma base de dados para ele usar, este arquivo deve ser incluso junto.

Comment: Obrigado bigown